# jQuery Show/Hide by class when multiple items contain the said class

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, jquery-animate

Thanks in advance for helping me out (for those who have time and are willing).

I've written this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  // (a little sooner than page load)
  $('.foliobtn').hide();
  $('.folionamedate').show();

  // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  $('.foliobottom').mouseover(function() {
    $('.foliobtn').show();
    return false;
  });
  $('.foliobottom').mouseout(function() {
    $('.foliobtn').hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.foliobottom').mouseover(function() {
    $('.folionamedate').hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('.foliobottom').mouseout(function() {
    $('.folionamedate').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

and put it onto this page http://www.fraservalley-webdesign.com/portfolio/test.php.

It works except it of course shows/hides on every element with the appropriate classes, not just the one I'm hovering over.  I can't uniquely name each one as there will be dozens and it will be database driven content.

Does anyone know a simple way to isolate the item I'm hovering over within the script?

Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense, and the answer is:  *Dont do that*.  Don't hide by class, if you don't want to hide all elements that use that class.  Use a different selector. (*this* works)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable "this" is bound to the triggering element in the mouseover and mouseout handlers, so you can say something like

```
$('.foliobtn',this).hide();
```

to hide the elements with class "foliobtn" inside the triggering element.

Answer (score 5):

You can use another function as a callback, this would effectively act as a toggle of sorts, and make your code simpler.

Give this a shot:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  // (a little sooner than page load)
  $('.foliobtn').hide();
  $('.folionamedate').show();

  // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  $('.foliobottom').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.foliobtn').show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.foliobtn').hide();
  });

});
```

You also don't need to `return false` in this case because the browser has no default behavior for this element.

`return false` is more appropriate for something like `click` for an `<a>` or a form submit, but really you'd probably want to use `preventDefault()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
    // (a little sooner than page load)

    $('.foliobtn').hide();
    $('.folionamedate').show();

    // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
    $('.foliobottom').mouseover(function() { $(this).show(); return false; });
    $('.foliobottom').mouseout(function() { $(this).hide(); return false; });
```

Comment: why return false? you've also duplicated some lines.

Comment: Ah yes, I just copied the code in the question and edited. It’s late here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jquery [bind method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind):

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  // (a little sooner than page load)
  $('.foliobtn').hide();
  $('.folionamedate').show();

  // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  $('.foliobottom').mouseover(function(e) {
     $(this).find('.foliobtn').show(); 
     $(this).find('.folionamedate').hide();
  });
  $('.foliobottom').mouseout(function(e) { 
     $(this).find('.foliobtn').hide(); 
     $(this).find('.folionamedate').show();
  });
});
```

Here you don't change visibility of all elements based on the class, but find an element using this class, and the current node